# Naming my own firebase unique ID/Keys. Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to name my own keys whenever I push a data into firebase.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database().ref('players');
var theKey;
var newPostRef;

$(document).on('click', '#enter', getName);

function getName()
{
    var name = $('#user').val().trim();

    database.push({
        name: name
    });

}

database.on("child_added", function(childSnapshot){
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val;
    console.log('key', childKey)
    console.log('data', childData)

    }, function (errorObject) {

        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);

    })
```

The console.log('key', childKey) will show the randomly generated key which is usually a long string of random letters. How do I name my own keys?

Comment: why you want your own keys?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using push() function use set.

For instance:

```
usersRef.child("custom-column-name").set({   
        date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912", 
        full_name: "Alan Turing" 
});
```